# How to record the fact that the same relationship happened multiple times ("number of times" column vs. multiple rows)?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have the following ER diagram:

[image]

Say that I want to record the fact that the same student met with the same teacher twice. I can do that either by using multiple rows, for example:

[image]

Or by having a "number of times" column, for example:

[image]

Are these two implementations correct, or is one of them wrong? And if both are correct, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: The first solution allows you to store additional meta data about the meetings, e.g. the data and the duration.

Comment: "Correct" by what criteria?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Please read the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling stackexchange homework'. What do "wrong" & "correct" mean--and for what purpose & assumptions? What do you think the pros & cons are under those circumstances & why?